# How can I make a HorizontalScrollView's child's child have the width of the screen?

Tags: java, android, xml

So I've got a LinearLayout, that has the layout_width set to "match_parent", let's call that A.

Then there's a HorizontalScrollView within that, let's call that B.

Then there's a RelativeLayout within that, that I am using because of the rule that only allows 1 direct child int he scroll view, lets call that C.

Then within that I have multiple RelativeLayouts that I want to make the same width as A, alongside each other. Please help me with how I can accomplish this!

Here is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="9">

    // Used because ScrollView can have only 1 child.
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/directChild"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        // This is the RelativeLayout that I want to fill the screen width with.
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/howToMakeScreenWidth"
            android:layout_width="385dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find width of screen using below utility method.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
```

then assign that width to your child RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
yourRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relParams);
```

Comment: That will not work because if the first RelativeLayout is changed to match_parent it will be as long as the HorizontalScrollView, which stretches out beyond the edge of the screen.

Comment: Because the scroll view has the ability to scroll to the right, it will make the RelativeLayout stretch out to the length of the scroll-able distance of the ScrollView. As seen here: http://pasteboard.co/2STAt2Seg.png

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the line "RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); has the error "Cannot resolve constructor 'LayoutParams(int)'"